# Control Flow of async function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

In this code, callback function of `.then` is executed before the `console.log("still going on...")` but normally callback function of `.then` shall be posted to micro stack first before coming to call stack.

What is happening differently here and why?

```
async function test(){
    console.log("start");
    console.log("going on...");
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(() => resolve("promise value"), 5000);})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    console.log("still going on...");
}
test();
console.log("end.");
```

Output:

```
start
going on...
end.
promise value
still going on...
```

Comment: What do you expect `await` to do there?

Comment: i just want to suspend the async function until the promise is settled. trying different combinations to understand the control flow of event loop.

Comment: what is your expected output??

Comment: it seems, with `await` keyword the `.then` callback is not sent to the micro stack. but the reason is not clear.

Comment: "_i just want to suspend the async function until the promise is settled_" - Doesn't that explain why `"still going on..."` is logged last? Because the function is suspended until the promise is settled?

Comment: as per my understanding if `await` does nothing but suspending the function. then output should be: `start                                                                                         going on...                                                                                                                 end.                                                                                                                            still going on...                                                                                                           promise value`

Comment: because function inside promise is creating different execution content in which you have defined to wait for 5 seconds so only after 5 seconds .then will go to microtask

Comment: await keyword behaviour, Means No Synchronus will perform untill await programming logic got resolve and or got an Error (Rejected).

Comment: yes after 5 seconds the async function will resume the part written after `await` keyword by calling it to call stack. that part will encounter `.then` method first which will be call immediately as the promise is already fulfilled which will put the callback function in microtask and after that the call stack will proceed to `console.log` function and call it. then call stack will be empty, so the tasks in microtask will be called now which contains the callback function in this case. or is it the case that all the `.then` & `.catch` chained with promise are part of the promise created.

Comment: yes settled means it's either fulfilled or rejected as per MDN. in this case as per the code, it will always be fulfilled. but i understood the control flow. a promise chained by `.then` and/or `.catch` is finally settled when all the promises returned by the `.then` and/or `.catch` handlers one after another are settled. then only `await` will detect the promise as settled coz `await` will see the promise returned by the last `.then` or `.catch` and will resume the remaining function code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `then` and `catch` create new promises.
2. you await the catch's promise.
3. since your initial promise is resolved, then's callback is executed and the then's and catch's promises are resolved in a chain
4. then `console.log()` is executed after `await`

Comment: yes from trial n error the same thing i concluded and now you confirmed that. any resource from where i can understand JavaScript async behavior in details?

Comment: @ManasGhosh i always refer to mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1):

> after 5 seconds the async function will resume the part written after `await` keyword by calling it to call stack. that part will encounter `.then` method first which will be call immediately as the promise is already fulfilled

No. The `.then()` and `.catch()` methods will already have been called *before* the async function is resumed, in fact they have created the promise that is `await`ed. Your code is equivalent to

```
async function test(){
    console.log("start");
    console.log("going on...");
    const _p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(() => resolve("promise value"), 5000);});
    const _p2 = _p1.then((result) => console.log(result));
    const _p3 = _p2.catch((error) => console.log(error));
    await _p3;
    console.log("still going on...");
}
```

and not doing

```
async function test(){
    console.log("start");
    console.log("going on...");
    const _p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(() => resolve("promise value"), 5000);});
    await _p1;
    const _p2 = _p1.then((result) => console.log(result));
    const _p3 = _p2.catch((error) => console.log(error));
    console.log("still going on...");
}
```

(which would behave as described in your comment, and log "promise value" after "still going on")